# how to load next item from directory on menu item click?

Tags: java, swing, file, actionlistener, jmenuitem

Hi i am trying to fetch one by one item from selected directory but problem is that when i click on menu item next then all comes together from directory.
i have put actionlistener on menuitem click and try to store one by one item in string variable and print on console but at a time all item loads what i will have to do ?

my code :

```
final JFileChooser file;
file = new JFileChooser();

file.showOpenDialog(contentPane);
        mnLoadDirectory.add(mntmSelectDir);
        File[] filesInDirectory = file.getCurrentDirectory().listFiles();
        String FileNames;
        //int i=1;

        JMenuItem mntmNextItem = new JMenuItem("Next Item");

        for (int i = 0; i < filesInDirectory.length; i++) 
        {
            if (filesInDirectory[i].isFile()) 
            {
                FileNames = filesInDirectory[i].getName();
                if (FileNames.endsWith(".jpg") || FileNames.endsWith(".JPG"))
                {
                    System.out.println(FileNames);
                }
            }
        }   



        mntmNextItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {           

            }
        });     
        mnLoadDirectory.add(mntmNextItem);      

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
```

i don't have put all code, i just put a code related to this one only.

**any suggestion ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access filesInDirectory from inside your action listener you will need to declare it final

```
final File[] filesInDirectory = file.getCurrentDirectory().listFiles();
```

What you are doing is iterating all the files and printing out the file names it looks like you want to move your for loop into your action listener and add a break. So you'd have something like.

```
    mntmNextItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {   
            if(i == filesInDirectory.length) {
                System.out.println("You are at the end");
            }        
            else {
                for (; i < filesInDirectory.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (filesInDirectory[i].isFile()) 
                    {
                        FileNames = filesInDirectory[i].getName();
                        if (FileNames.endsWith(".jpg") || FileNames.endsWith(".JPG"))
                        {
                            System.out.println(FileNames);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: it shows an error that FileNames can not be assigned since it defined in enclosing type.

Comment: hey i have made it. i have just declare variable FileNames inside actionlistener and without final keyword. & i have put i++ before break. thank you so much. yaar.

Comment: Yes filenames is only used within the scope of the for loop so there would be no need to declare it outside or assign it there. You might also want to concider using java style formating for variable names. The convention is that capital letters are only used to name classes so someone else reading your code might thing that FileNames was a class and that it had a static method called endsWith

Comment: yes that's it what i have done. & from next time i will keep in mind about file naming convention.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear I was referiing to variable naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file contents into a `List` or array.  Maintain some kind of `int` value that points to the current element begin shown.

When you're ready to move to the next element, increment the `int` value, perform appropriate edge checks and update the display as required.

**Updated with simple example**

This is a basic example.  It scans a specified directory into a `List` and maintains a `int` index of the current file.

When the `next` menu item is actioned, it simple increments the `int` index value and updates the display

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class NextFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NextFile();
    }

    private FilePane filePane;

    public NextFile() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                filePane = new FilePane();
                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
                mb.add(fileMenu);
                JMenuItem mntmNextItem = new JMenuItem("Next Item");
                fileMenu.add(mntmNextItem);

                mntmNextItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        filePane.nextFile();
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(filePane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FilePane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField path;
        private List<File> files;
        private int fileIndex = -1;

        public FilePane() {

            File parentPath = new File("/path/to/your/directory");
            File[] childFiles = parentPath.listFiles();
            files = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(childFiles));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            path = new JTextField(20);
            add(path);

            nextFile();

        }

        public void nextFile() {
            if (files.size() > 0) {
                fileIndex++;
                if (fileIndex >= files.size()) {
                    fileIndex = 0;
                }
                path.setText(files.get(fileIndex).getPath());
                path.setCaretPosition(path.getText().length());
                path.moveCaretPosition(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but where ti put that code ? means where to use actionlistener ? i am confused about that, if any help from your side then it will be so welcomed.

Comment: The actual mechanisms will come down to what it is you want to achieve, but basically you need two things.  You need some kind of `List` or array of the `File`s and a current index value of the currently displayed `File`.  In your action listener, you would need to increment the index file and get the next file from the list...

Comment: Where?  Did you use something like `files = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(childFiles));` from my example to convert an array to an `ArrayList`

Comment: i have taken all code as sample in separate file named NextFile but it show me error.

Comment: May be you could updated you question with additional example for where you're up to...